# Celery task is always PENDING inside Docker container (Flask + Celery + RabbitMQ + Docker)

Tags: python, docker, rabbitmq, celery

I'm creating a [basic project](https://github.com/rmmariano/test_flask_celery_docker) to test Flask + Celery + RabbitMQ + Docker.

For some reason, that I do not know, when I call the celery, the task seems to call RabbitMQ, but it stays at the PENDING state always, it never changes to another state. I try to use [task.get()](https://github.com/rmmariano/test_flask_celery_docker/blob/master/app.py#L27), but the code freezes. Example:

[image: example 1]

The celery worker (e.g. [worker_a.py](https://github.com/rmmariano/test_flask_celery_docker/blob/master/worker_a.py)) is something like this:

```py
from celery import Celery

# Initialize Celery
celery = Celery('worker_a',
                broker='amqp://guest:guest@tfcd_rabbit:5672//',
                backend='rpc://')
[...]

@celery.task()
def add_nums(a, b):
   return a + b
```

While [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/rmmariano/test_flask_celery_docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L16) is something like this:

```
  [...]
  tfcd_rabbit:
    container_name: tfcd_rabbit
    hostname: tfcd_rabbit
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.11-management
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE=test
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    networks:
      - tfcd

  tfcd_worker_a:
    container_name: tfcd_worker_a
    hostname: tfcd_worker_1
    image: test_flask_celery_docker
    entrypoint: celery
    command: -A worker_a worker -l INFO -Q worker_a
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    links:
      - tfcd_rabbit
    depends_on:
      - tfcd_rabbit
    networks:
      - tfcd
  [...]
```

The repository with all the files and instructions to run it can be found [here](https://github.com/rmmariano/test_flask_celery_docker).

Would anyone know what might be going on?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, a friend of mine discovered the problem:

The correct queue name was missing when creating the task, because Celery was using the default name "celery" instead of the correct queue name.

The final code is this:

```py
[...]
@celery.task(queue='worker_a')
def add_nums(a, b):
   return a + b
```